# How to make my elements occupy the available space of a column using flexbox?

Tags: css

I have 2 containers, and I'm trying to make them both have the same height. I'm using flexbox to solve this problem using the property `flex-direction: column (flex-column)` but I do not know what I'm doing wrong so that each element is divided by height of the available container.

[image]

```css
.borde_gris_b{
  border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row p-0 m-0 m-auto justify-content-center">
     <!-- first container-->
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-xl-4 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">
            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">SNIES</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
                <div class="card-text">12967</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Duración</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 10 periodos academicos </p>
            </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Número de Créditos</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 170 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Modalidad de Formación</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Presencial </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- two container-->
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0 m-0 ">
        <div class="row p-0 m-0">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column" >
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0" >

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 ">Becas</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
                        <div class="d-flex mb-1">
                            <div class="mr-3"> Beca Bien </div>
                            <div>

                                <p > $2,107,000 </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Valor Matrícula</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> $5,696,000 </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
  
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Jornada</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Diurna/Nocturna </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end row -->
```

I need both elements to have the same height, and that the elements present in each container are distributed by the available height of the container.

Comment: why repeating the same question if you already accepted an answer before on the old one?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.borde_gris_b{
  border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}

.red-border{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row p-0 m-0 m-auto justify-content-center">
     <!-- first container-->
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-xl-4 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column red-border">
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">
            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">SNIES</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
                <div class="card-text">12967</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Duración</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 10 periodos academicos </p>
            </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Número de Créditos</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 170 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Modalidad de Formación</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Presencial </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- two container-->
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0 m-0 red-border">
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0" >
                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mb-1 ">Becas</h6>
              
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-row">
                            <span class="mr-3"> Beca Bien </span>           
                                <p class="mb-0"> $2,107,000 </p>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Valor Matrícula</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> $5,696,000 </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
  
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Jornada</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Diurna/Nocturna </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</div><!-- end row -->
```

Comment: check this pen if you need the second column cells to stretch the height available
https://codepen.io/soothran/pen/LKoywM

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. It may help you. I gave a class .container-2 to the 2nd container and configured it as flexbox.

```css
.borde_gris_b{
  border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}

.container-2 {
    display: flex;
    align-self: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row p-0 m-0 m-auto justify-content-center">
     <!-- first container-->
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-xl-4 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">
            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">SNIES</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
                <div class="card-text">12967</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Duración</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 10 periodos academicos </p>
            </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Número de Créditos</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 170 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Modalidad de Formación</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Presencial </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- two container-->
    
    <div class="container-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0 m-0 ">
        <div class="row p-0 m-0">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column" >
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0" >

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 ">Becas</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
                        <div class="d-flex mb-1">
                            <div class="mr-3"> Beca Bien </div>
                            <div>

                                <p > $2,107,000 </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Valor Matrícula</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> $5,696,000 </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
  
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Jornada</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Diurna/Nocturna </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end row -->
```